# Проблемы при подключении кода для Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, компиляция

Хотел просто написать код для Unity
Но появилась проблема и вот что мне говорит VisualStudio:

> не удалось разрешить основную ссылку "UnityEditor.Graphs", поскольку она косвенно зависит от сборки платформы "System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", которую нельзя разрешить в текущей целевой платформе. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Subset v3.5". Чтобы устранить эту проблему, удалите ссылку "UnityEditor.Graphs", или измените целевую платформу приложения на версию, которая содержит "System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Unity.TextMeshPro

Код

```
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using UnityEngine;  

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {  
    public float verticalImpulse;  
    Rigidbody2D rb;  
    // Use this for initialization  
    void Start () {  
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();  
    }  

    // Update is called once per frame  
    void Update () {  

    }  
    void FixedUpdate()  
    {  
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))   
        {  
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, verticalImpulse), ForceMode2D.Impulse);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

- появляются такие ошибки

  > CS2001  Не удалось найти исходный файл "C:\Users\Gaming PC\Documents\Platformer\Packages\com.unity.textmeshpro\Scripts\Runtime\TMP_TextInfo.cs".
  >   CS2001  Не удалось найти исходный файл "C:\Users\Gaming PC\Documents\Platformer\Packages\com.unity.textmeshpro\Scripts\Runtime\FastAction.cs".

  Их штук 45

Comment: Ну так вы, возможно, хотели еще и код приложить к своему вопросу?:)

Comment: Это точно весь код? Да и текст ошибки не полный.

Comment: А вы пробовли игнорировать то, что пишет студия, и запустить это в юнити? Не знаю как сейчас (какая-то интеграция там со студией есть), но раньше юнити использовал свой компилятор и студия частенько показывала ошибки, когда в самом юнити все компилировалось и работало. (А, кстати. Вам не нужно ничего компилировать в студии, просто сохрантте код и запустите вашу игру в эдиторе)

Comment: Игнорирование работает.Только интересно стоит ли обращать внимание на эту проблему

Comment: Нет.. Не стоит.

Comment: Ну у вас как минимум не установлен TextMeshPro. Версия Unity 2018? Вы, судя по всему, поставили еще и пак для разработки 2д платформера? Об этом стоит указывать в вопросе, что я и попросил сделать.